# Is it a good idea to schedule a daily CHECKPOINT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Checking our production logs from yesterday, we discovered a period of about 5 minutes when a whole bunch of really simple queries were timing out. Further investigation on the server logs showed a huge spike in disk activity, which [led me to the conclusion](https://serverfault.com/q/332825/23577) that an automatic CHECKPOINT was being run on the DB at that time.

That's something I really don't want to happen during peak hours. So I was thinking of scheduling a daily CHECKPOINT every day during off-peak hours.

Is that a good idea? Bad idea? Waste of time? If not that, then what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's hard to know this for sure given the limited information here, but I don't think you're quite down to root cause yet.

- Why did a huge spike in disk activity make you think the root cause was a checkpoint?
- Why would the best fix be running a checkpoint manually?
- Have you checked into which queries were running at the time, and what their wait stats were?

Checkpoints already happen much more frequently than daily - the [default in 2016 is every minute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server).

So to answer the question:

- Adding a daily checkpoint would be a bad idea and ineffective
- Consider doing more troubleshooting like checking the server's wait stats
- For a followup, [include server config and wait stats info in your question](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/10/getting-help-slow-server/) (disclaimer: that's my blog post)

Comment: Thank you, those tools look excellent. I'm setting up the SQL server to save stats every 5 minutes, and hopefully I'll be able to come back to this question with some more useful metrics.

Comment: If I want to look back over the past 24 hours to identify performance problems, and I've been logging as per the section on your blog, "Storing sp_BlitzFirst Results in a Table", what's a good query to run that will highlight problematic logs?

Comment: Sure, check the Power BI Dashboard for DBAs in that First Responder Kit download. It gives you a visual way to surf through the data. Unfortunately, teaching you how to do performance tuning is a little beyond the scope of what I can pull off in a Stack Exchange answer, heh.

Comment: Eh, I don't see anything in that download called "Power BI Dashboard"...? :-/

Comment: It's in the Power BI folder. If not, you might have an old version - go get the current ones.

Comment: I only see 2 files there, one .pbix and one .pbit. How do you open those?

Comment: Check the readme for instructions, which takes you here: https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/ Keep in mind that further "how do I do this" questions in the comments probably won't be productive. Hope that helps!